# ¿Por qué utilizando doble punto puedo llamar las funciones asociadas a un dato numérico?

Tags: javascript

Esta manipulando unos datos desde la consola de *DevTools* en *Google Chrome* en donde a una variable numérica quería aplicarle una función directamente, es decir, de la forma siguiente:

```
> 100.toExponential()
VM1583:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Lo que intentaba hacer era algo similar a cuando utilizas una cadena de texto como:

```
> '100'.toString()
"100"
```

Es decir, sin necesidad de almacenar en una variable mandar a llamar directamente una función asociada al tipo de dato.

Como pueden ver al realizar directa la llamada a la función falla, con el mensaje anterior mostrado, así que realice unas cuantas pruebas más para conocer un poco de los datos:

```
> a = 100
100
> a.toExponential()
"1e+2"
> Number("100").toExponential();
"1e+2"
> Number(100).toExponential();
"1e+2"

> ({}).toString.call(100.)
"[object Number]"
> typeof 100
"number"
> typeof a
"number"
```

Pero lo que buscaba era mandar a llamar *"directamente"* las funciones de una variable numérica así que intente lo siguiente que por cierto funcionó:

```
> (100).toExponential();
"1e+2"
> 100..toExponential()
"1e+2"
```

La segunda forma me agrada y busque un poco más al respecto sobre por qué funcionaba y encontré los siguientes enlaces:

- [JavaScript: WTF?!?](https://martin-thoma.com/javascript-wtf/#weak-typing)
- [What is the double-dot operator (..) in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211641/6415698)

#### ¿Alguien que tenga conocimiento de qué sucede por detrás de esta expresión `100..toExponential()` y de por qué esto funciona?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El caso que expones: `100.toExponential( )` no funciona por la sencilla razón de que un número **inmediatamente seguido** de un punto, es la forma de representar **número decimal** o **de coma flotante**.

El compilador, al encontrarse el punto `.`, espera **un dígito** a continuación; en lugar de eso, encuentra un caracter, y *se queja*.

Para solventar lo que pretendes, llamar directamente a funciones en literales numéricos **sin producir ambigüedad**, el lenguaje proporciona varios *métodos alternativos*:

1. Encerrar el número entre paréntesis `( 100 ).toExponential( )`.
2. Dejar **un espacio** entre el número y el punto: `100 .toExponential( )`.
3. Colocar un **salto de línea** entre el número y el punto:

   ```
   100
      .toExponential( )
   ```
4. Utilizar **dos puntos** `..` en lugar de uno: `100..toExponential( )`.
5. Utilizar un **número decimal**, colocando un `0`: `100.0.toExponential( )`.

Cualquiera de estos métodos es suficiente para que el compilador sepa que el número ha terminado, y siga *parseando* a partir de ahí.

<sub>Todo esto puede verse en la página de la [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), en perfecto inglés.</sub>

#### Edito

Gracias al comentario de [@Angel Oropeza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7334/angel-oropeza), añado otra forma: usando la *invocación mediante corchetes*:

6. Usando *corchetes* `[]` para delimitar el nombre del método: `100["toExponential"]( )`.

Comment: Interesante, no sabía que existía documentación al respecto. Por cierto, de acuerdo a la documentación que colocaste el punto `3.` y `4.` son incorrectos ya que debe ser `100 .toExponential( )`.

Comment: Adicional, gracias a tu orientación pude encontrar más información en particular esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380077/why-cant-i-access-a-property-of-an-integer-with-a-single-dot) que añade una nueva forma: `100["toExponential"]()`

Comment: ¡ Huy ! Cierto, *gazapo* por mi parte. Editado. Esa forma que dices, la verdad es que no se me hubiera ocurrido :-O

Comment: En realidad, todas ellas vienen a ser mas o menos lo mismo. *Finalizar* el número antes de que el compilador encuentre el punto. Con tu permiso, añado la forma *con corchetes* a la respuesta.

Comment: ¡Adelante! Eso ayudaría bastante a quién se tope con este tema.